# How to iterate over two Collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, loops

I'd like to use a for each loop to iterate over two Collections. My first idea was:

> foreach (object o in a.Concat(b)) {
>   o.DoSomething(); }

But the problem is, not all Collections support Concat. So what do to?

Comment: If you have Linq availible, look at the SelectMany method.

Comment: See if http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Is the body of loop as simple as you've described in the example? If so, I'd opt for a simple solution: two foreach loops, one after the other.

Comment: @asawyer, `SelectMany` is not the solution here. By `Concat` not being available, you should deduce he is not dealing with `IEnumerable<T>`. `SelectMany` will not be initially available, either.

Comment: @Anthony Good point, didn't consider that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some legacy collection types implement only `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`, and therefore don't have the `Concat` extension method. You can solve this by first using the method [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) and specifying the generic type you want, then it will work with `Concat`.

Comment: I believe you mean `Cast<T>`. `Enumerable.ToEnumerable<T>` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks but i get this error when trying it. 'System.Linq.Enumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToEnumberable'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ...

```
foreach (object o in a.Concat(b)) {
o.DoSomething(); }
```

Why not just ?

```
foreach (object o in a) {
  o.DoSomething();
}
foreach (object o in b) {
  o.DoSomething();
}
```

If you really want them to be both in the same list, construct a new list and add them together before you start processing.

Comment: various reasons, duplicated code, new object instantiation, more memory necessary, ...

Comment: +1 for simple solution.  Rofl, those reasons aren't valid in this simple example.  In fact, it uses less memory, fewer objects and the "duplicated" line is one object method call.  Sometimes clarity is best.

Comment: Concat'ing the lists will still take up more memory, as you'll have to expand one list to accommodate the added references.  Your code should follow the processing in the simplest way FIRST, and then after it works, you should look for optimizations.  Duplicating code means something else in this context.

Comment: as a note, using `Concat` will not expand either list. That's not its job; it exists to work with `IEnumerable<T>` sequences and results in a lazily evaluated sequence, where the elements of the first sequence will be followed by the elements for the second as they are requested. If a concrete list is needed, that would be a call to `ToList()` which would then result in a new list being created from the concatenated sequence.